# how to prevent an href to show another page till first page is filled completely

Tags: jquery, html

i have a link in mobile jquery..

```
  <div data-role="page" id="main" data-title="Main Page">
```

Here there are two textboxes which must be filled by the user. Then here is a link..

```
  <a href="#sub" data-role="button" id="save" data-icon="star" data-theme="b" data-transition="flip">Show Employee Data</a>
```

"sub" is data-role="page" which displays the data of these 2 textboxes.
I wrote in .js..

```
  $(document).delegate('#save', 'click', function(e) {
       if(document.getElementById('name').value=="")
       {  alert('Name Not Entered..');e.preventDefault();return false;  }
  });
```

Every thing runs good, Alert is also shown, but second page is also shown because of href having id="save". All i need is to show this second page only after validation of first page.. Am i doing something wrong ?? Please suggest..

--EDIT-- I saw in break mode in chrome that just after clicking href second page gets loaded and then it enters in code. I have to stop this loading of second page immediately.. Is there anything we can write in a href"$sub" ...  > ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my problem solved.. I wrote

```
  $(document).ready(function() 
  {
      $("#save").click(function(e)
      {
          if(document.getElementById('name').value=="")
          {  
             alert('Name Not Entered..');e.preventDefault();return false;  
          }
          if(document.getElementById('surname').value=="")
          {  
             alert('Surname Not Entered..');e.preventDefault();return false;  
          }
      });
  });
```

});

Now the second page is not showing just by clicking on href, but shows after validation of the first page.
Thanks for help..

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
$(document).delegate('#save', 'click', function() {
  var valid = undefined;
  $(':text').each( function() {
    valid = valid === undefined || valid ? $(this).val().length > 0 ? false;
  });
  if(valid) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('validation failed.'); return false;
  }
});
```

Explanation for the validation:

1. valid is initially undefined
2. if valid is undefined or true, check if this input has a value, if not set valid to false
3. if valid is not undefined or true, keep it false because if one input has no value then validation fails

If you want to make sure that they type in for example more than 3 letters, make `$(this).val().length > 2`.

Comment: "show this second page only after validation of first page" - please tell us exactly what you want to validate against.

Comment: There are two text boxes on the first page and user should enter something in both of them, then only second page should show. That's it..

Comment: And it's just "something", doesn't matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Try `return false;`, instead of `return;`. That should prevent the default behavior of the link, or alternatively include the event in your function arguments [`function(ev){...`] and call `ev.preventDefault();`.

You might want to check out: [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Good luck!

Also, try using click() instead of delegate() and you're missing a parenthesis at the end:

```
$("#save").click(function(e) {
    if(document.getElementById('name').value=="")
    {  alert('Name Not Entered..');e.preventDefault();return false;  }
})
```

Comment: I tried e.preventDefault(); but second page is loading immediately after click the link and afterwards it enteres the validation code. Is there anything we can write in <a href="#sub" ... >

Comment: After taking another look, I see you have a syntax error in your javascript. You're missing a parenthesis at the end ). Put that there and everything should work fine. Also you don't need both (return false; and e.preventDefault()). One or the other is enough. Also, try using click() instead of delegate().

Comment: but $(document).click(function(e) { }); runs by clicking anywhere on the page. Will it be right ? Code should run by clicking on associated button and here button is href..

Comment: yeah sorry, oversight. I meant $("#save").click()

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way....instead of "a", you can have ID

```
$(function(){

  $("a").click(function(e){

      if($("#txtName").val().length === 0)
      {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }    
  });
});
```